# Polyhedrons and their centers of mass

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Given a convex polyhedron, one considers 3 possibilities:

- wireframe - only the edges of the polyhedron have mass which is uniformly distributed.
- surface - only the surface is massive with uniform distribution.
- solid - the interior has a uniform mass distribution.

In each case, we can define a center of mass (CM) - which will obviously lie somewhere in the interior. We shall call them the wireframe CM, surface CM, solid CM. If a polyhedron has a large number of small faces in one corner, its wireframe CM can get pulled very close there but the other CMs are more 'robust'.

**Questions:** Which tetrahedron of unit diameter maximizes the distance between a given pair of CMs? Which tetrahedron maximizes the area of the triangle formed by the 3 CMS?

Which is the closed convex surface (not necessarily polyhedral) with unit diameter for which the surface CM and the solid CM are farthest apart.

**Note:** In 2D, it is known that the wireframe CM of a triangle T is the incenter of its medial triangle (the triangle with mid points of the sides of T as vertices) - and the surface CM of T is of course, its centroid. I do not know which planar convex figure of diameter 1 maximizes the distance between the wireframe CM and surface CM.

**Further Question:** One can also ask: given a tetrahedron and its three massive forms (wireframe, surface and uniform solid), how different could its the *principal axes of inertia* be?

Comment: For completeness, why not consider the CM of the vertices too?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Maybe because like the wireframe CM, the vertex CM can also be shifted to an arbitrary position in the polyhedron with arbitrarily small effect on the higher dimensional CMs and on the polyhedron itself.

Comment: At least for tetrahedrons , yes I guess (although the 'vertex CM' too can be pulled way 'off-center' by bunches of small faces)! Thank you..

Comment: The vertex CM and solid CM seem to coincide for all tetrahedrons. That appears to leave us with 3 CMs at least for tets.

Comment: What is your unit of distance? (Scaling multiplies all distances on an arbitrary positive factor.)

Comment: i guess the "unit diameter" condition is enough to take care of scaling issues.

Comment: To provide a lower bound: if you take a prism of height $\epsilon$ whose base is an isosceles triangle with base $\epsilon^2 $ and height $1$, the distance between the surface COM and the centroid will be $1/3$. (The same lower bound holds in 2D by considering only the triangular base.)

Comment: Thanks.  Guess what you mean is a prism with (1) its base an extremely narrow based isosceles triangle with diameter 1 and (2) height of the prism is much less than 1 but much more than the *base of its base triangle*. For this object, most of the surface area comes from the two equal vertical faces. The area CM will then be at a distance almost 1/2 from the mid point of the 3rd and very thin vertical face and the solidCM is the centroid, 1/3 away from the mid point of this thin vertical face. This gives a distance of 1/6 between  surface CM and solid CM and that could well be an upper bound.

Comment: And in 2D, the wifreframe CM of such a very narrow based isosceles triangle of diameter 1(same as the incenter of its median triangle) is almost at a distance 1/2 from the mid point of its base and hence at distance 1/6 from its centroid which is the area CM. So, 1/6 may again be the upper bound. Thanks

Comment: A tetrahedron with 3 very narrow and unit diameter isosceles faces and one tiny equilateral face would give 1/6 as the limiting distance between its wireframe CM and volume CM. That *might* be the answer to one of the questions on max separated pairs of CMs for tetrahedrons.

Comment: I am downvoting this because it asks too many questions, and because it asks for optima of functions when the OP has not shown values of those functions in any particular case. I’d remove the downvote if the post was narrowed to less than five questions (I count “for each pair of centers” as three questions) and if it provided at least one non-trivial value for each function whose optima it requests.